# Gender problem in a django i18n translation

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I need to solve a gender translation problem, and Django doesn't seem to have [gettext contexts](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Contexts) implemented yet...

I need to translate from english:

```
<p>Welcome, {{ username }}</p>
```

In two forms of spanish, one for each gender. If user is a male:

```
<p>Bienvenido, {{ username }}</p>
```

and if is a female:

```
<p>Bienvenida, {{ username }}</p>
```

note the difference (bienvenido/bienvenida)

Is there any way of getting this done?

Thanks,

H.

Comment: Just as an update to this issue, contextual markers are now supported in Django 1.3 :http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#contextual-markers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is just Python so you can use the Python gettext bindings directly if you need to, I don't see any reason you couldn't write a {% gender_trans [gender] %} tag.

Comment: "gender_trans" may not be the perfect naming for the tag :-)

Comment: Python gettext library does not support contexts, see http://bugs.python.org/issue2504. Babel does not help here too, since msgctx support is planned for 1.0 release, see http://babel.edgewall.org/milestone/1.0

Comment: In the OP example, the gender depends on the content of a variable: so, we need a way to extract 'gender' from 'username'!

Comment: @zgoda Python 3.8 at last does support `pgettext` and similar functions that take a context: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.pgettext

Answer (score 10):

The way that I've solved this is:

```
{% if profile.male %}
{% blocktrans with profile.name as male %}Welcome, {{ male }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% else %}
{% blocktrans with profile.name as female %}Welcome, {{ female }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for contexts to be supported, an easy alternative would be to slightly change the Spanish sentence and use a greeting that does not vary according to a person's gender. For example, you could use "hola", or some other equivalent term.

Comment: It may work for Spanish, but not for other translated languages (if any...)

Comment: Contexts are supported now in Django.

Answer (score 0):

**Django translation supports [contextual markers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers).**

The thing is you need to use **pgettext**, not gettext. Importing it `pgettext as _` caused it to not work properly for me, most likely because of how `manage.py makemessages` works.

```py
from django.utils.translation import pgettext


pgettext("feminine", "Dear %(name)s")
pgettext("masculine", "Dear %(name)s")
```

Which then allows you to add contextual translations in .po file:

```
#: path/to/file.py:4
msgctxt "masculine"
msgid "Welcome, %(name)s"
msgstr "Welcome, %(name)s"

#: path/to/file.py:5
msgctxt "feminine"
msgid "Welcome, %(name)s"
msgstr "Welcome, %(name)s"
```